# Add a dimension to a nifti file

Tags: python, numpy, reshape, nifti, nibabel

I have nifti file (.nii) with a shape of `(112, 176, 112)`. I want to add another dimension to it so that it becomes `(112, 176, 112, 3)`. When I try `img2 = np.arange(img).reshape(112,176,112,3)` I get an error.
Is it possible to do this with `np.reshape` or `np.arange` or any other way?

Code:

```
import numpy as np
import nibabel as nib

filepath = 'test.nii'  
img = nib.load(filepath)
img = img.get_fdata()

img = np.arange(img).reshape(112,176,112,3)

img = nib.Nifti1Image(img, np.eye(4))
img.get_data_dtype() == np.dtype(np.int16)
img.header.get_xyzt_units()
nib.save(img, 'test_add_channel.nii')
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-f6f2a2d91a5d> in <module>
      8 print(img.shape)
      9 
---> 10 img2 = np.arange(img).reshape(112,176,112,3)
     11 
     12 img = nib.Nifti1Image(img, np.eye(4))

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do'it this way:

```py
import numpy as np

img = np.random.rand(112, 176, 112)  # Your image
new_img = img.reshape((112, 176, 112, -1))  # Shape: (112, 176, 112, 1)
new_img = np.concatenate([new_img, new_img, new_img], axis=3)  # Shape: (112, 176, 112, 3)
```

Probably that is other better way to do'it, but the code above give you the output you want.